# Storing currency exchange is MongoDB

Tags: php, json, mongodb, currency

is this the way you would store currency exchange rates for mongoDB?
It does work for us, but some limitations I see if its going to be hard for us to do a date/time search instead what we will have to do is split the date and time and then place it in a select drop down or something.

Please give me your views.

```
{
   "currentexchange": {
     "0": {
       "to": "NZD",
       "rate": "1.2879",
       "updated": "8: 42pm" 
    },
     "1": {
       "to": "USD",
       "rate": "0.9777",
       "updated": "8: 42pm" 
    },
     "2": {
       "to": "KWD",
       "rate": "0.2739",
       "updated": "8: 42pm" 
    },
     "3": {
       "to": "GBP",
       "rate": "0.6354",
       "updated": "8: 42pm" 
    } 
  },
   "exchangehistory": {
     "2012-06-06T09: 51: 25+10: 00": {
       "0": {
         "to": "NZD",
         "rate": "1.2875" 
      },
       "1": {
         "to": "USD",
         "rate": "0.9768" 
      },
       "2": {
         "to": "KWD",
         "rate": "0.2742" 
      },
       "3": {
         "to": "GBP",
         "rate": "0.6351" 
      } 
    },
     "2012-06-06T10: 00: 09+10: 00": {
       "0": {
         "to": "NZD",
         "rate": "1.288" 
      },
       "1": {
         "to": "USD",
         "rate": "0.9774" 
      },
       "2": {
         "to": "KWD",
         "rate": "0.2743" 
      },
       "3": {
         "to": "GBP",
         "rate": "0.6354" 
      } 
    },
     "2012-06-06T10: 15: 07+10: 00": {
       "0": {
         "to": "NZD",
         "rate": "1.2878" 
      },
       "1": {
         "to": "USD",
         "rate": "0.978" 
      },
       "2": {
         "to": "KWD",
         "rate": "0.274" 
      },
       "3": {
         "to": "GBP",
         "rate": "0.6357" 
      } 
    },
     "2012-06-06T10: 30: 10+10: 00": {
       "0": {
         "to": "NZD",
         "rate": "1.2873" 
      },
       "1": {
         "to": "USD",
         "rate": "0.977" 
      },
       "2": {
         "to": "KWD",
         "rate": "0.2737" 
      },
       "3": {
         "to": "GBP",
         "rate": "0.6352" 
      } 
    },
     "2012-06-06T10: 45: 08+10: 00": {
       "0": {
         "to": "NZD",
         "rate": "1.2879" 
      },
       "1": {
         "to": "USD",
         "rate": "0.9777" 
      },
       "2": {
         "to": "KWD",
         "rate": "0.2739" 
      },
       "3": {
         "to": "GBP",
         "rate": "0.6354" 
      } 
    } 
  },
   "from": "AUD" 
}
```

So how we plain on using this.

When a user wants to withdraw money, we need to be able to get the exchange rate that they requested the withdrawal.

We also need to be able to do LIVE conversion rate changes if a user has two types of currencies and say there default is AUD and they are paying someone in USD then we need to convert it, or if they dont have enough USD and they have AUD then we need to dip into there AUD and convert some to pay the rest of the charge.

Comment: What type of queries do you expect to run? Understanding the big queries is key to modeling your data.

Comment: @GatesVP I have edited above to explain how we plain on using it.

Comment: looks like your collection is going to have one document per currency? that could be very problematic as it will keep growing unbounded...

Comment: @AsyaKamsky yes you are correct, I am going to look into this, but I am not sure what I should do to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues to consider here: use of IDs & multiple collections

**Use of Ids**

Your data format seems off. Consider the following in a `currentExchange` collection:

```
"_id" : "AUD",
"NZD": { "rate": "1.2879", "updated": "8: 42pm" },
"USD": { "rate": "0.9777", "updated": "8: 42pm" },
 ...
```

This will be the easiest layout to query.

**Multiple Collections**

You will want to break out `currentExchange` and `exchangeHistory` into two collections. You want the `currentExchange` to remain small and it will leverage different indexes.

As you designed it, your document would become very large and then fail.

Comment: @Gates_VP I understand what you mean so would each exchange history, be stored as a new row or collection?

Comment: Each exchange history would be a new row in a "history" collection. You could index those items on the `from` or the `to` or some combination: `AUD_USD_201205071205` would be an easy to identify unique key. If you wanted the history of AUD to USD, sorted you could do a `find({_id: /^AUD_USD/}).sort({_id:1})`.